# (HTML)Cant store the browser height into variable and use the same in a class which is used for a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

How do I get the height of the browser window in jquery and use that in a class in CSS.I used this code but it doesn't work , some modifications are needed

```
<style>
.browserHeight
{
height:h ;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="container browserHeight"> ANOTHER PAGE 
</div>
</body>

<script>
var h=$(window).height()+"px";
</script>
```

Comment: Would `100vh` or `100%` do the trick without JS?

Comment: No, 100% isn't adding the same height as I used for my first (vertical) page.

Comment: Why not set the css in the javascript. You can't pass a variable from js to css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass a variable into CSS like this. However, using jquery, you can add CSS to an element.

Remove the `style` part altogether.

Your `<script>` becomes:

```
var h=$(window).height();
$('.browserHeight').css("height",h);
```

Note that I removed the `+"px"` part from where you define `h`.